# DiscordJS bot JIMP show the first image with the first command but not the second time

Tags: node.js, image, discord.js, image-manipulation

i have a problem with discordJS and Jimp, it look like a discord bug but i'm not sure.
When i'm doing my first command after a restart, it send the image properly but the second time i execute the command, it send me a downloadable file without crashing [screen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdvmc.png)

here's my code :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Jimp = require('jimp');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
        if (interaction.commandName === 'evil') {
            if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'user') {
                const user = interaction.options.getUser('mention');
                const toptext = interaction.options.getString('toptext')
                const bottext = interaction.options.getString('bottomtext')

                const font = await Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE);
                const image = await Jimp.read(user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png',size: 256 }));
                image.invert()
                .print(font, 0, 5, {
                    text: `${toptext}`,
                    alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER
                }, 256, 256)
                .print(font, 0, 220, {
                    text: `${bottext}`,
                    alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER
                }, 256, 256)
                .write('invert.png')
                await interaction.reply({
                    files: [{
                      attachment: 'invert.png',
                      name: 'file.png'
                }]});
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You should probably save each result with an unique filename – otherwise concurrent invocations of the command could get each others' results.

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting for Jimp to write the image. Also, you'll want to use an unique filename for each invocation of the command; otherwise it's possible two users would write to the same file at the same time.

Something like

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Jimp = require('jimp');
const fsp = require('fs/promises');

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    if (interaction.commandName === 'evil') {
      if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'user') {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('mention');
        const toptext = interaction.options.getString('toptext');
        const bottext = interaction.options.getString('bottomtext');
        const tempFile = `invert-${+new Date()}.png`;  // Unique filename
        const font = await Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE);
        const image = await Jimp.read(user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png', size: 256}));
        image.invert();
        image.print(font, 0, 5, {
          text: `${toptext}`,
          alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
        }, 256, 256);
        image.print(font, 0, 220, {
          text: `${bottext}`,
          alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
        }, 256, 256)
        await image.writeAsync(tempFile);  // Wait for the image to be written.
        await interaction.reply({
          files: [{
            attachment: tempFile,
            name: 'invert.png',
          }],
        });
        await fsp.unlink(tempFile);  // Remove temporary file once we're done
      }
    }
  })
}
```

might work for you.

Comment: thank you ! it almost worked but it's just a little mistake on the interaction.reply